# free-jqgrid drag and drop not working. click on row highlights data in cells

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I don't seem to be able to get the drag and drop to work.  When I click on a row in the jqfrid1 table, it just highlights the cell's data that I am clicking on.  I cannot seem to grab the whole row.
Version 4.13.6

```
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = @Html.Raw(@Model.jsonCls);
    var MyQData = @Html.Raw(@Model.MyRpts);

    $(document).ready(
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $("#jqgrid1").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("List", "Home")',
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            colModel: [
                { name: "Tracis" , label: "Tracis", width:80},
                { name: "CrimeType", width:200},
                { name: "Supp", formatter: 'checkbox' ,width:30},
                { name: "Arrest" , formatter: 'checkbox', width:30},
                { name: "Type", formatter: 'string', width:85},
                { name: "Reported", formatter: 'string', width:100}    //formatter:"date", formatoptions: { newformat: "mm/D/Y" } , 
            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true },
            rowNum: 30,        // Total records to show at a time by default
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],  // For Paging
            pager: true,
            datastr: data,
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            hoverrows: true,
            caption: "Unassigned"
        });

        $("#jqgrid2").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("List", "Home")',
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            colModel: [
                { name: "Tracis" , label: "Tracis", width:80},
                { name: "CrimeType", width:200},
                { name: "Supp", formatter: 'checkbox' ,width:30},
                { name: "Arrest" , formatter: 'checkbox', width:30},
                { name: "Type", formatter: 'string', width:85},
                { name: "Reported", formatter: 'string', width:100}  
            ],

            rowNum: 30,        // Total records to show at a time by default
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],  // For Paging
            pager: true,
            datastr: MyQData,
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            height: 'auto',
            hoverrows: true,
            caption: "My Queue"
        });


        jQuery("#jqgrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqgrid2'});
        jQuery("#jqgrid2").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqgrid1'});

    }));

</script>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}
<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h2>Report List:</h2><br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="jqgrid1"></table>

        </td>
        <td style="background-color: black">

        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="jqgrid2"></table>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you included `jquery-ui.min.js`, which provides Drag&Drop functionality.

jqGrid requires `jquery-ui.min.css` for the base functionality, but some other options like `sortable: true` to reorder columns with respect of Drag&Drop or the methods like `gridDnD` to reorder the rows, required `jquery-ui.min.js`.

I suggest you that you verify that you have included both CSS and JS of jQuery UI.

Comment: I was missing both of those files.  That makes it work for me.  Thank you.

Comment: When I drag a row from one table to the other, the order of the data gets changed and the values end up in the wrong columns.  Do I need to fix this with an event? or is this a settings I am missing?

Comment: @SDanks: It's better if you post the exact options of `gridDnD`. Do you used `dropbyname` option, for example?. It's important to know the `colModel` of both grids. One can use `beforedrop` callback to customize the data of dropped row before it will be inserted in new grid. You can post new question if you will don't solve the problem yourself. It's better to include the demo (in JSFiddle, for example) in the question.

Comment: @SDanks: See [the lines of code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L782-L822) of `gridDnD` for more details about `dropbyname` option and `beforedrop` callback.

Comment: I was just using the code shown above.  The columns are the same and in the same order. I will look at dropbyname.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it.  I used dropbyname:  jQuery("#jqgrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqgrid2', dropbyname: true});
        jQuery("#jqgrid2").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqgrid1', dropbyname: true});

Comment: @SDanks: I see that you voted questions and answer of stackoverflow only 31 times in 4 years and 8 months. *Voting be used by searching engine*. It's the most important criteria to help other to find **really helpful** information of stackoverflow. You have right to vote about 32 answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). Please you the right if you want to help other people.